# New file/database in OmniFocus 2 for macOS

Tags: mac, file, macos, omnifocus

When first starting to use OmniFocus, it opens with some example data preloaded for practice.

Am I supposed to delete that bogus data, and continue to use that existing file/database for my own data? Or am I supposed to create a new distinct file or database for my own real data?

I’ve tried looking through the manual. But I do not see anything about new files or about backing up my database.

Comment: Assuming you don’t store the data in iCloud or use onmi sync server, the delete is pretty well documented https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/create-new-database-start-from-scratch/9701/5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, there is no way to create a separate new file/database in Omni Focus 2. The default workflow is to use the pre-created database along-with the built-in backup feature.

You can create a new OmniFocus 2 database by following the steps as mentioned in the Omni Group thread, [Create new database / start from scratch?](https://discourse.omnigroup.com/t/create-new-database-start-from-scratch/9701)

> Once you're satisfied with the state of your backups, you can remove your current OmniFocus database:
>
> 1. Hold down the Command key and click on the small icon at the top center of your OmniFocus window.
>      In the menu that pops up, select the second item (a folder named "OmniFocus"):
> 2. Hold down the Command key and click on the small icon at the top center of your OmniFocus window.
>      In the menu that pops up, select the second item (a folder named "OmniFocus"):
>
> [image]
>
> 3. This will open a new Finder window. Once this window opens, quit OmniFocus.
> 4. In the Finder window, delete the file named OmniFocus.ofocus, as well as any files ending in lock.
> 5. Close this Finder window and relaunch OmniFocus.
>
> You should be prompted to create a new database, either from a sync server (usually Omni Sync Server, or perhaps your own WebDAV server) or simply by setting up the default database locally. I usually start with the latter.
>
> If you do have your data synced to a server, and you want to get rid of that as well, set up a local database and tweak it to your heart's content. Once you've done that, you can set up sync with your existing sync server, then choose File / Replace Server Database... to erase any sync data on the server, putting your new empty database online in its place. Be careful - this means your only copies of your old database are the backups on your computer!

Comment: That seems like a buried feature. Is the norm to just use the given default file and not worry about files/databases in OmniFocus?

Comment: Yes it's a bit convoluted. The workflow is to use the default database along-with the built-in backup feature.

Comment: Can you add that explanation at the top of your Answer.  Then it will completely satisfy my question.

Comment: Updated the answer.